# RelativeLayout. 2 views. v1 exactly over v2

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-view

I have layout `RelativeLayout`. This layout have different views: v1, v2 and other. At runtime I can change `LayoutParams` of v2: margins, width, height. I want that view v1 always will be over v2 with some margins and size, BUT without any code (at runtime as v2). Yes, I can also set margins and size for v1, but I'm curious: is this issue can solve only with `xml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy. Move both views: v1 and v2 in one parent view and change only parent view margins/size.